# Sri Vaishnavism - What to do?

Tags: bhakti

I am interested in becoming a Sri Vaishnava. I am not initiated yet.

Please guide me as to what should I do as a Sri Vaishnava? What rules should I follow? What books should I read? Anything else I should watch out for?

Answer (score 2):

Adiyen Ramanuja Dasan
We have a community of Sri Vaishnavas on discord you should join it for guidance  :
https://discord.gg/hHT4UeCnUH
In any case you should start by the following books.
https://archive.org/details/vaisnavism-its-philosophy-theology-and-religious-discipline-sm-srinivasa-chari-2000

https://archive.org/details/fundamentalsofvisistadvaitavedantabasedontattvamuktakalapabyvedantadesikasmsrinivasachari2004ocr/mode/2up?view=theater

Comment: Hi remember me from theos discord :)

Comment: Yeah I do remember

Comment: Yay :D my Vaishnava brother.

Comment: Thanks a million